# How do I solve an IP address conflict caused by a VPN connection?

Tags: networking, vpn, ipv4, opnsense, ip-conflict

I have my own home LAN, and run an OPNsense (a fork of pfSense) router to control it. I use the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet.

One of my computers (in reality, a VM running inside Proxmox) connects to a VPN server over which I have no control. This server hands out whatever IP it pleases, often in the 10.0.0.0 subnet. This IP regularly conflicts with existing machines on my LAN.

Unfortunately, I struggle with advanced network topics.

I believe I should be able to use opnSense to perform the actual VPN connection, and somehow "re-map" the IP handed to me by the VPN to some more acceptable IP, e.g. one on the 192.168.0.0 subnet. Is this possible? Or is another solution possible?

- I do not want to change my local machines to use IPv6 addresses, because that would make their IPs impossible to memorise and prohibitively long to type.
- For the same reason, I don't want to abandon the 10.0.0.x subnet. (Besides, that wouldn't be a perfect solution in any case, because I may need to connect to other VPN servers in the future.)
- I cannot connect to the VPN server using IPv6.

Comment: Try putting your home network on a less common subnet. That is what I do to prevent the issue you have.

Comment: To be honest, there is no good solution to site-to-site VPN when both sides have the same IP range. large enterprises can use two source NAT walls to trick each network into believing their counterpart  is on a different subnet, but that kind of option is out of reach for most admins. Sorry, there is no magic bullet that will make this work.

Comment: There's no way, using opnSense or VMs or the like to solve the problem? So my only option is to continue to have IP conflicts?

Comment: Can't you change your own DHCP server to use a different IP-range than `10.x`?

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't solve the problem. Six months from now I could connect to a different VPN and they'd be using whatever subnet I had switched to. I thought this kind of nonsense was one of the things a real router was supposed to solve.

Comment: Plus I'd probably have to reinstall Proxmox. As I recall, it doesn't cope well with changes to the network settings.

Comment: it will never be possible to completely eliminate the possibility that you might end up wanting to create a remote link to a network with the same IP range. I think you will find that it is in fact very rare as long as you don't set up any networks using default ranges like 10.0.0.0/8 or 172.16.0.0/16 or 192.168.0.0/24.